# Is there an Application URL Protocol for opening pdf file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking to open pdf/image file on user computer using angula 6.

I have tried with following but nothing worked

acrobate|http://example.com/myTestDocument.pdf

I need similar code for pdf and images for loading from user computers as we have for word in below code snippet

ms-word:ofe|u|http://example.com/myTestDocument.docx

Pdf was not getting opened

Answer (score 1):

No.

Custom URL schemes are typically only used when linking to something which *isn't* a file (for instance: opening a chat with a specific user in a specific messengering application).

For the opening of files, the `Content-Type` response header suffices. Applications can register themselves to handle specific file types.

Since most modern browsers have native support for PDF files, they don't typically open in Adobe Acrobat (or whatever application the user has set as their preference for PDF files) by default.

Comment: Thanks for response but we are looking to load file from user local pc and there we can't set content type. is there any other way to load file from user local folder